# Resolve metadata of a torrent from the hash (or the magnet link)? Ideally in python

Tags: python, p2p, bittorrent, magnet-uri

I'm trying to take a magnet link (ie. `magnet:?xt=urn:btih:640FE84C613C17F663551D218689A64E8AEBEABE`) and fetch the metadata for it (title, files, comment, whatever else comes with a .torrent file). Ideally in python, but I'll take any info I can get

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251305/torrent-info-and-magnet-links-in-libtorrent-python-bindings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. [libtorrent](https://libtorrent.org/)
2. [python bindings](https://libtorrent.org/python_binding.html)

You are welcome.

Comment: This is the library used by Deluge, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Magnet2Torrent](https://github.com/danfolkes/Magnet2Torrent), which uses python and python-libtorrent to download a torrent file for any magnet uri that it is given.